# By enabling Google Sign-In i am getting this error com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

Tags: java, android

I'm enabling Google-SignIn options to my android app but getting the Exception as com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:, i do have created the OAuth client ID and I'm not enabling any firebase to my project. And moreover i do have followed each and every steps as per theGoogle Documentation. I'm getting the error in here.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in debug apk or in signed apk?

Comment: regenerate SHA-1 key and add it to firebase console and retry

Comment: it was in debug apk

Comment: Even after regenerating the SHA-1 Key and by adding firebase console the error remains the same

Comment: To eliminate any possibilities of error, delete the existing google-services.json file from your project , download the latest  google-services.json file having your SHA-1 from firebase console, add it to your project rebuild & install (uninstall the older one), also please check your web client id is correct or not.

Comment: I did everything as you said but still the error is the same